# Sharepoint page not working after some days

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I have a sharepoint page created and it works fine on local as well as on sharepoint ,problem is that after some days page goes down and we could not perform the operations which it intended to be ,but if i upload the same page again it works fine can any one tell me whats the problem

Comment: Can you be more explicit please? What does your page do? Is it a html or an application page? How did you wrote the page (designer, visual studio, ...)?

Comment: it contains form which we use to upload result but that is not problem it works fine for few days.

Comment: Can you at least post the contents of your page or describe which type of paging are we talking about?

Comment: Page contains simple javascript Ajaax call and HTml table